# Calling a method with an generic parameter with Java reflection

Tags: java, reflection, jboss

I need to call this method : public  T unwrap(Class iface) from a class that I can't import.

I'm trying to do this :

```
 Class jbossWrappedSt = Class.forName("org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6");

 Method metodoUnwrap = jbossWrappedSt.getDeclaredMethod ("unwrap", new Class[]{Class.class});
 Object val = metodoUnwrap.invoke (st, new Object[] {PreparedStatement.class});
```

But fails with a NoSuchMethodException exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.jdk6.WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6.unwrap(java.lang.Class)

Class javadoc :
https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/org/jboss/ironjacamar/jdbc-local/1.0.28.Final/jdbc-local-1.0.28.Final-javadoc.jar-unzip/org/jboss/jca/adapters/jdbc/JBossWrapper.html#unwrap%28java.lang.Class%29

**Update**: I forgot to say that we are using Java 1.5 (Yeah! I know).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for a *declared* method which precludes the possibility to receive an *inherited* method. So if `WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6` inherits the method from `JBossWrapper` or some other class in the class hierarchy instead of declaring it itself, the lookup will fail. You should use `getMethod` which will provide you the method regardless of where in the class hierarchy it is defined, provided the method is `public` which is the case here.

Nevertheless, since it’s defined in standard Java API [`Wrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Wrapper.html#unwrap-java.lang.Class-) `interface`, there is no need to use Reflection at all. If the compile-time type of `st` is not already `PreparedStatement`, you can simply invoke `((Wrapper)st).unwrap(PreparedStatement.class)`.

Answer (score 1):

The class in the Javadoc is

org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.JBossWrapper

however the class you are looking at is a different class.

The class you are look at doesn't have an unwrap method.

https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/unzip/unzip/org/jboss/ironjacamar/jdbc-local/1.0.28.Final/jdbc-local-1.0.28.Final-javadoc.jar-unzip/org/jboss/jca/adapters/jdbc/jdk6/WrappedPreparedStatementJDK6.html

getDeclaredmethod doesn't follow the inheritance heirarchy to find a method like getMethod does.

As the method is `public`, I suggest you use `getMethod` and you won't need to know the class which actually implements the method.

In fact you should be able to call the public method directly, but I assume there is a reason you have to use reflection.

Comment: As I said ;^). But actually, Reflection is unnecessary…

Comment: @Holger I would hope this is a simplified example, and there is a reason the OP needs reflection, but I could be wrong. ;) +1